# Grid System not working correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, division

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6FL3.png)

I am using the col-xs-6 col-md-3 division but when i get to the 6th line , the positioning of the item sways to the right can anyone please help me rectify this problem.

> Blockquote

#### Amino X2

```
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/fishoil.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Fish Oil</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/jympre.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Jym</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/supercharge.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Super Charge</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/arnoldironmass.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Arnold Mass</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/mass-tech.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Mass Tech</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/upyourrmass.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Up Your Mass</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/goldwhey.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Whey Protein</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/c4big.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>C4</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/animalpump.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Animal Pump</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/celltech.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Cell Tech Creatine</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/platinumcreatine.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Platinum Creatine</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/dailyformula.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Daily Formula</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/seriousmass.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Serious Mass</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/truemass.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>True Mass</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/cellmass.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>True Mass</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/carnivor.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Carnivor Protein Bar</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/combatcrunch.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Combat Crunch Bar</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/universalprotein.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Universal Hi Protein Bar</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/hydroxycut.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Hydroxycut</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/hydroxycut.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Hydroxycut</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <img class="img" src="img/png/hydroxycut.png" alt="" style="width: 200px; height:200px" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Hydroxycut</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I asked this question because this was the first time i am facing this issue and the other references .. as in the question being asked already doesnt really answer my question

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: i just edited the question section please check